# Saving Python list containing Tensorflow Sparsetensors to file for later access?

Tags: python, json, tensorflow

I'm creating a list of Sparsetensors in Tensorflow. I want to access them in later sessions of my program. I've read online that you can store Python lists as json files but how do I save a list of Sparsetensors to a json file and then use that later on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A Tensor in TensorFlow is a node in the graph which, when run, will produce a tensor. So you can't save the SparseTensor directly because it's not a value (you can serialize the graph). If you do evaluate the sparsetensor, you get a SparseTensorValue object back which can be serialized as it's just a tuple.

Comment: So I would first evaluate the SparseTensor inside of Session and then I can store that result inside of a json file?

Comment: I should be able to do this simply by using json.dumps(list_of_sparsetensors) right?

Comment: with SparseTensorValue, yes, I think